# Xref error while parsing PDF using PyPDF2 and pdfrw?

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf, pdfrw

I am trying to extract the text from the following [PDF](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/files/4292903/1.pdf).

First, I used the `PyPDF2` library. I used the following code:

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
pdf = PdfFileReader('March_5_8000/1.pdf',strict=False)
information = pdf.getDocumentInfo()
```

This throws the following error:

```py
/opt/conda/envs/fastai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py in getObject(self, indirectReference)
   1597             if debug: print(("  Uncompressed Object", indirectReference.idnum, indirectReference.generation, ":", start))
   1598             self.stream.seek(start, 0)
-> 1599             idnum, generation = self.readObjectHeader(self.stream)
   1600             if idnum != indirectReference.idnum and self.xrefIndex:
   1601                 # Xref table probably had bad indexes due to not being zero-indexed

/opt/conda/envs/fastai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py in readObjectHeader(self, stream)
   1665             warnings.warn("Superfluous whitespace found in object header %s %s" % \
   1666                           (idnum, generation), utils.PdfReadWarning)
-> 1667         return int(idnum), int(generation)
   1668 
   1669     def cacheGetIndirectObject(self, generation, idnum):

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'obj'
```

I also tried using the `pdfrw` library, but that returned the same error: 
Code:

```py
from pdfrw import PdfReader
x = PdfReader('March_5_8000/980.pdf')
x.keys()
```

ERROR:

```py
PdfParseError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-6d3575671b6c> in <module>
      1 from pdfrw import PdfReader
----> 2 x = PdfReader('March_5_8000/980.pdf')
      3 x.keys()

/opt/conda/envs/fastai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pdfrw/pdfreader.py in __init__(self, fname, fdata, decompress, decrypt, password, disable_gc, verbose)
    617             while 1:
    618                 source.obj_offsets = {}
--> 619                 trailer, is_stream = self.parsexref(source)
    620                 prev = trailer.Prev
    621                 if prev is None:

/opt/conda/envs/fastai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pdfrw/pdfreader.py in parsexref(self, source)
    463             return self.readdict(source), False
    464         else:
--> 465             source.exception('Expected "xref" keyword or xref stream object')
    466 
    467     def readpages(self, node):

/opt/conda/envs/fastai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pdfrw/tokens.py in exception(self, *arg)
    227 
    228     def exception(self, *arg):
--> 229         raise PdfParseError(self.msg(*arg))

PdfParseError: Expected "xref" keyword or xref stream object (line=2238, col=39, token='obj')
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Isn't there a problem with passed filename?

Comment: Oh, sorry. That's just a name I passed. There exists a similar file (to the one I uploaded) on my disk.

Comment: Can you try again with the latest version of PyPDF2?